# Как правильно оформить метод для рисования на C#?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Я пишу небольшую программу, которая должна давать пользователю возможность рисовать мышкой. В принципе у меня все получилось, но меня беспокоит то, как оно рисует линию, вот код метода:

```
private void mainPictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   startPoint = e.Location;
}

private void mainPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{    
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
   {
      drawPen = new Pen(penColorGlobal, penSizeTrackBar.Value);

      movePoint = e.Location;

      Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mainPictureBox.Image);

      g.DrawLine(drawPen, startPoint, movePoint);
      startPoint = movePoint;

      drawPen.Dispose();
      g.Dispose();

      mainPictureBox.Invalidate();
   }
}
```

В коде видно, что при опускании мыши на рисунок (`MouseDown`) мы заносим в объект `startPoint` типа `Point` начальные координаты, то есть координаты откуда начинаем рисовать. В самом методе `MouseMove` мы указываем, что рисовать мы будем линию от `startPoint` до `movePoint` (movePoint - траектория по которой движется наша мышь).
Все работает, но есть одно но... Если внимательно присмотреться, то можно увидеть, что нарисованная нами линия по диагонали (допустим) будет состоять не из сплошной линии, а из каких-то крестиков 0о! Это особенно заметно при увеличении размера линии.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это исправить, или может я где-то допустил ошибку в коде, если так то исправьте.
Заранее всем Спасибо!

Немного повозившись, я докодился до того, что мой метод MouseMove принял такой вид:

```
private void mainPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) //РИСУЕМ ЛЕВОЙ КЛАВИШЕЙ МЫШИ
   {
      drawPen = new Pen(penColorGlobal, 1);
      Brush fillBrush = new SolidBrush(penColorGlobal);

      Size size = new Size(penSizeTrackBar.Value, penSizeTrackBar.Value);
      Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(startPoint, size);

      Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mainPictureBox.Image);
      g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; //Сглаживание

      g.FillEllipse(fillBrush, rectangle);
      g.DrawEllipse(drawPen, rectangle);

      startPoint = e.Location;

      drawPen.Dispose();
      g.Dispose();

      mainPictureBox.Invalidate();
}
```

Этот код рисует уже без крестиков, и вид намного лучше. Но теперь появилась совсем другая проблема.
Когда мы рисуем с не очень большой скоростью, все выглядит замечательно, но когда мышка начинает ускоряться (может, ее резко дернули или еще что-то) линия идет не сплошная, а рывками, а так как у мы рисуем кругами, это плохо, потому как они рисуются отдельно.

Теперь помогите разобраться с такой проблемой:)
Еще раз всем спасибо!

Скриншоты:
**рисование с линииями**
[image]

**рисование с кругами**
[image]

Comment: Можете скриншот выложить?

Comment: Уже выложил

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще один вариант, при котором не видно разрывов: запоминать точки в MouseMove и рисовать их заново.

```
    private void mainPictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _points = new HashSet<Point> {e.Location};
    }

    private void mainPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) //РИСУЕМ ЛЕВОЙ КЛАВИШЕЙ МЫШИ
        {
            return;
        }

        _points.Add(e.Location);

        using (var drawPen = new Pen(penColorGlobal, penSizeTrackBar.Value))
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(mainPictureBox.Image))
        {
            g.DrawLines(drawPen, _points.ToArray());
        }

        mainPictureBox.Invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Все таки все сделал, немного конечно помучался но довел до ума:

```
 private void mainPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
       {
          drawPen = new Pen(penColorGlobal, 1);
          Brush fillBrush = new SolidBrush(penColorGlobal);

          Size size = new Size(penSizeTrackBar.Value, penSizeTrackBar.Value);
          Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(startPoint, size);

          Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(mainPictureBox.Image);
          g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

          g.FillEllipse(fillBrush, rectangle);
          g.DrawLine(drawPen, startPoint, e.Location);

          startPoint = e.Location;

          drawPen.Dispose();
          g.Dispose();

          mainPictureBox.Invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще говоря, без размывания косая по отношению к расположению пикселей линия всегда будет рисоваться лесенкой. Если Вы посмотрите внимательно на какой-нибудь Microsoft Word, увидите, что там то же самое. Если проблема в этом, для размывания посмотрите в сторону `System.Drawing.Drawing2D`.

Comment: После добавления своего поста я додумался и всунул в код строку:
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

Эфект замечен я вам скажу, но не настолько как нужно.